# Rails ActiveStorage uploads work locally but AWS & GCS uploads fail with 500 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rails-activestorage

I've just finished implementing ActiveStorage uploads to my Rails 6 app.

I'm uploading an image when I create an Organisation.  The organisation gets created, and the image gets added to the two tables - `active_storage_attachments` and `active_storage_blobs`.

My application logs then say the image was uploaded to Google Cloud Storage (or AWS), and displays a 500 Server Error followed by a System Stack error.

```
17:06:30 web.1     |    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
17:06:30 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/organisations_controller.rb:45:in `update'
17:06:30 web.1     |   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" INNER JOIN "active_storage_attachments" ON "active_storage_blobs"."id" = "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 2], ["record_type", "Organisation"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:06:30 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/organisations_controller.rb:45:in `update'
17:06:30 web.1     |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 2], ["record_type", "Organisation"], ["name", "image"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:06:30 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/organisations_controller.rb:45:in `update'
17:06:30 web.1     |   ActiveStorage::Blob Create (40.9ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "4e1y1yhbggpS6ncqnqd0j8y0knvxkx"], ["filename", "logo-icon.png"], ["content_type", "image/png"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["byte_size", 2055], ["checksum", "VT91aKRpVPAZnzNeOLdeQQ=="], ["created_at", "2021-03-21 17:06:30.892165"]]
17:06:30 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/organisations_controller.rb:45:in `update'
17:06:30 web.1     |   ActiveStorage::Attachment Create (3.6ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_attachments" ("name", "record_type", "record_id", "blob_id", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "image"], ["record_type", "Organisation"], ["record_id", 2], ["blob_id", 20], ["created_at", "2021-03-21 17:06:30.940291"]]
17:06:30 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/organisations_controller.rb:45:in `update'
17:06:30 web.1     |    (0.5ms)  COMMIT
17:06:30 web.1     |   ↳ app/controllers/organisations_controller.rb:45:in `update'
17:06:31 web.1     |   S3 Storage (241.6ms) Uploaded file to key: 4e1y1yhbggp6ncqnq0j8y0knvxkx (checksum: VT91aKRpVPAZnzNeOLdeQQ==)
17:06:31 web.1     | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 408ms (ActiveRecord: 58.9ms | Allocations: 105587)
17:06:31 web.1     | 
17:06:31 web.1     | 
17:06:31 web.1     |   User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
17:06:31 web.1     |   
17:06:31 web.1     | SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
17:06:31 web.1     |   
17:06:31 web.1     | app/controllers/organisations_controller.rb:45:in `update'
```

My application then hangs and I need to restart it.  I check the Google Cloud bucket, and the image **hasn't** been added.  I've tried the exact same steps with AWS and the same error occurs.

Does anyone know what's going on here?  When I use local disk storage, everything works as expected.

Here are my configs:-

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0.rc2'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false
```

**config/storage.yml**

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: eu-west-1
  bucket: app-local
```

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

**models/organisation.rb**

```
class Organisation < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

**controllers/organisations_controller.rb**

```
  def update
    if @organisation.update(organisation_params)  ### This is line 45 which is erroring
      redirect_to @organisation, notice: 'Organisation was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

**views/organisations/_form.html.erb**

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :image %>
    <%= form.file_field :image, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
```

Is there a way to get more log info from the AWS or GCS gems, or **something** I can try to diagnose this further?  The 500 error isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be that I was getting "Access denied" from AWS - so my permissions in AWS were somehow set up wrongly.

I only learned this because I turned Access Logs on in AWS (off by default), so was able to at least diagnose it further than the 500 error.